# Defining default values as an array in Ruby results in values being overwritten

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am working on some code that takes in a `sending_destination` object (which are instructions on how to send some data to a group of people).

```
  sending_destination = MyApp::Model::SendingDestination.where(:id => some_id)
  destination_hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }

  sending_destination.each do |destination|
    if destination.send_to_group?
      group_users = destination.address # this retrieves n-number of `User` objects
      group_users.each do |user|
        destination[:address] = user.user_id
        destination_hash[job_signature(destination)] << destination
      end
    end
  end
```

The above code takes in a `destination` object, retrieves the `user_id` of this user, and assigns it to `destination`'s `address` field. So let's say I have 3 users of IDs `1`, `2`, and `3` respectfully, then `destination[:address]` for each user would become 1, 2, and 3.

And this is the definition of `job_signature`:

```
private_class_method def self.job_signature(destination)
  format = destination[:format]
  "#{format}|#{!!destination[:apply_formatting]}|#{!!destination[:apply_vis]}|#{destination.id}"
end
```

This just generates a string based on the properties within `destination` and is then the key used per destination for the following `destination_hash`.

```
destination_hash[job_signature(destination)] << destination
```

The above line of code results in the following hash - the `:address` value would be incremented in each loop where the key is `job_signature(destination)` and the value is `destination`.

```
{"csv|false|false|1" => [
MyApp::Model::SendDestination {
  : id => 1,
  : scheduled_plan_id => 1,
  : type => "email_group",
  : format => "csv",
  : address => "1",
  : apply_formatting => false,
  : apply_vis => false,
}]}
```

Everything seems to work fine.. except all my values (the `MyApp::Model::SendDestination` part) within `destination_hash` gets replaced by the last assigned `destination` object. For example, one would expect the respective `:address` of 3 `destination`s assigned are 1, 2, and 3. But when I print out the `destination_hash` outside of the `.each`, all `destination` objects show the `:address` of 3.

The following is the resulting `destination_hash` object. As you can see, the `:address` value is all `3`. Instead, it should be 1, 2, and 3.

```
{
  "csv|false|false|1" => [
  MyApp::Model::SendDestination @values = {
    ... # I removed the unnecessary key-values for demo purposes
    :address => "3", # this should be "1"
    ...
  }],
  "csv|false|false|2" => [
  MyApp::Model::SendDestination @values = {
    ...
    :address => "3", # this should be "2"
    ...
  }],
  "csv|false|false|3" => [
  MyApp::Model::SendDestination @values = {
    ...
    :address => "3", # this is correct
    ...
  }]
}
```

So my question is - why are all my destination objects being replaced by the last object assigned?

Comment: Do you mind pointing out specifically what you mean by hash key? I'm not entirely understanding your question

Comment: I've been pausing my debugger at the line prior to `destination_hash[job_signature(destination)] << destination`, and `destination` shows the correct information (the right `user_id`). But after the append to `destination_hash`, the `destination` object isn't what I thought I assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that when you push `destination` into one of the values of `destination_hash` here:

```
destination_hash[job_signature(destination)] << destination
```

you push the actual object and not a copy (ie by reference and not by value).

This means that when you change the `destination` object in the next iteration here:

```
destination[:address] = user.user_id
```

you change the object everywhere it exists including where you pushed it last time.

Try replacing

```
destination_hash[job_signature(destination)] << destination
```

with

```
destination_hash[job_signature(destination)] << destination.clone # or equivalent
```